# Matching audio files with text using java

Tags: java, javasound

I have a collection of audio files. Now, I have a piece of text (say a lyric) that i want to match with the audio files? In other words, which audio file contains this lyric. I am curious how we can do this in Java. I would prefer a solution that uses preprocessing of the audio files so that the search is fast.  Is there any API that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognizing words is hard.  Recognizing words in songs is even harder.

It sounds like you are not interested in how to do that, but more to locate things in your song database.  If so, the simplest way to do so, may be to locate lyrics for each song based on its title and other meta data, and then just search in that text.

Comment: *"Recognizing words in songs is even harder."* 'scuse me while I kiss this guy. ;)

Comment: @Thorbjorn: Suppose I have converted the audio files to text myself. I can manually match the text now. But then how can you play the audio file that contained the lyric exactly at that lyric

Comment: You will need to store the time of each word in the lyric when converting it.  This allow you to get the time.   You then just need to invoke a suitable program capable of playing your audiofile at that location.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'd need speech recognition.  The [JSAPI](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/) might be a way to go, but last time I checked, only text-to-speech parts (they are plug-ins provided by 3rd parties) were available, not the other way around.